# GZip Website Compression Query

Tags: .htaccess, caching, compression, gzip, pagespeed

I have a small question.

I run an e-commerce site which updates daily. Following advice, I added the following lines to my .htaccess file in order to improve my site's speed.

## compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Now, my problem is that when I load up my website it loads a cached version. Being an e-commerce site, I need to display the latest stock information at any given time etc.

I'm unfamiliar with this whole topic and the above code was originally copied from another source, hence, can someone advise me what to remove/replace with in order to maintain the best site speed and also avoid caching on my product pages etc.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

These lines only turn on mod_defalate, which compresses your content, it has nothing to do with caching.

You are probably getting a cached version because of varnish or some other cache proxy that is set up between you and the site.

If you want to make sure that the page is not cached, you should add no-cache headers to your html. For example, something like:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
  Header unset Etag
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
```

This tells browsers and proxies not to cache the .html and .htm pages on your site.